# Hive - Create a nested Hive table from another non-nested Hive table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, nested

I have a hive table - Table A as follows:

```
id | partner | recent_use | count |
1  | ab      | 20160101   | 5     |
1  | cd      | 20160304   | 12    |
2  | ab      | 20160205   | 1     |
2  | cd      | 20150101   | 2     |
3  | ab      | 20150401   | 4     |
```

From Table A, I want to end up with a table like this - Table B:

```
id | partner |
1  | [ ab : { recent_use:20160101, count:5 } , cd : { recent_use:20160304, count:12 } ]
2  | [ ab : { recent_use:20160205, count:1 } , cd : { recent_use:20150101, count:2 } ]
3  | [ ab : { recent_use:20150401, count:4 } ]
```

Basically, Table B is a nested version of Table A such that for a given id, all the data from each of its partner is grouped into one column.

I have two questions:

1. How can I create Table B from Table A?
2. How can I convert Table B into a JSON document such that I can load the document into any NOSQL DB?

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple to achieve this is using UDAF - user defined aggregation function. You can write custom function to make things simple. Here is some thing you can using inbuilt functions. Give it a try.

> select id, CONCAT("[", concat_ws(',', collect_set(CONCAT('"', partner,
>   '":{ "recent_use":', recent_use, ', "count":', count, "}"))), "]") as
>   collJ from tableA group by id

Above SQL will get ID and collJ in string you looking for after that can use get_json_object function to convert to JSON object.

Reference

https://www.qubole.com/resources/cheatsheet/hive-function-cheat-sheet/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy